# How to populate `identifier` and `providers` in Firebase custom authentication?

Tags: php, firebase, php-jwt

I'm authenticating my users on my web service and then creating [Firebase custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) via [php-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt):

```
// Requires: composer require firebase/php-jwt
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;

// Get your service account's email address and private key from the JSON key file
$service_account_email = ...;
$private_key = ...;

function create_custom_token($uid, $is_premium_account) {
  global $service_account_email, $private_key;

  $now_seconds = time();
  $payload = array(
    "iss" => $service_account_email,
    "sub" => $service_account_email,
    "aud" => "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
    "iat" => $now_seconds,
    "exp" => $now_seconds+(60*60),  // Maximum expiration time is one hour
    "uid" => $uid,
    "claims" => array(
      "premium_account" => $is_premium_account
    )
  );
  return JWT::encode($payload, $private_key, "RS256");
}
```

But the users that I authenticate this way, don't show the administrator-friendly "Identifier" and "Providers" fields in the "Authentication" panel in the Firebase Console:

[image]

The first two are users that I authenticated via this custom authentication process, and the last one is a user that I authenticated directly via Google.

How can I populate the "Identifier" and the "Providers" fields for users created via custom authentication?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "Providers" column will only display an icon if the information attached to a user matches one or more of the the given providers in the "Sign-In Methods" section (https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/providers).

Custom providers don't have a distinct icon, and Firebase wouldn't know what to display in the "Identifier" column (the UID is already in its own column at the end).

However, you *do* have some control for the display of the columns by creating them in advance (meaning: before signing them in for the first time), or by updating the user information after the user entry has been created.

I prepared an example showing which combination of fields leads to which display:

[image]

Please note:

- The display name has no effect: if it is the only data provided, the user is considered anonymous.
- Email + Password match the "Email/Password" Provider
- Phone Numbers will alway match the "Phone" provider
- The icons for a matched provider will be displayed in the column, even if a provider has been disabled.
- Emails and Phone numbers have to be unique. If your application allows multiple users with the same email address/phone number, you will get into trouble, if you just want to see more information about the users of your Firebase project.

You can create and update users via the [Firebase Auth REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/), but I would suggest to use one of the official Firebase Admin SDKs SDK to do it - in case you want to stick to PHP, I happen to know an unofficial one: [kreait/firebase-php](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php) ([Documentation](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/)) (Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of the PHP SDK :) ).

On a non-technical note: I wouldn't bother too much with the user list in the Firebase Web Console: use the Firebase CLI tool or one of the official (or unofficial ;) ) Admin SDKs to create an overview that meets your needs.

You mentioned in the Bounty Annotation that you asked this in the Firebase Slack Community without an answer - you can find me and other PHP developers in the #php channel. I enabled notifications for the channel, so please feel free to join if you have further questions.

---

FYI, this is the code I wrote with the PHP SDK to create the data for the screenshot above:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use Kreait\Firebase;
use Kreait\Firebase\Util\JSON;

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$serviceAccount = Firebase\ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__.'/service_account.json');

$firebase = (new Firebase\Factory())
    ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)
    ->create();

$auth = $firebase->getAuth();

// Remove all users
foreach ($auth->listUsers() as $user) {
    $auth->deleteUser($user->uid);
}

// Simulate custom auth
$ct = $auth->createCustomToken('a-custom-auth');
$r = $auth->getApiClient()->exchangeCustomTokenForIdAndRefreshToken($ct);
echo JSON::prettyPrint($auth->getUser('a-custom-auth'));


echo JSON::prettyPrint($auth->createUser([
    'uid' => 'displayname-only',
    'displayName' => 'Jérôme Gamez',
]));

echo JSON::prettyPrint($auth->createUser([
    'uid' => 'email-only',
    'email' => 'jerome@example.org',
]));

echo JSON::prettyPrint($auth->createUser([
    'uid' => 'email-and-password',
    'email' => 'jerome@example.com',
    'password' => 'password'
]));

echo JSON::prettyPrint($auth->createUser([
    'uid' => 'phone-only',
    'phoneNumber' => '+49-123-1234567',
]));

echo JSON::prettyPrint($auth->createUser([
    'uid' => 'email+name+phone',
    'email' => 'jerome@example.net',
    'displayName' => 'Jérôme Gamez',
    'phoneNumber' => '+49-123-7654321',
]));

echo JSON::prettyPrint($auth->createUser([
    'uid' => 'email+name+password+phone',
    'email' => 'jerome@example.de',
    'displayName' => 'Jérôme Gamez',
    'password' => 'example123',
    'phoneNumber' => '+49-321-7654321',
]));
```